# How to convert React Native (expo) app to Android native code (and is it even possible)?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, converters

Some time ago, we decided to go multiplatform with React Native, from start it looked like a good pick - most of the things more or less worked the same on Android and iOS, however over time we were encountering more and more pitfalls - visual demands that were not cross-platform, very unstable permission checks across multiple android versions, some difficulties with styling and unstable releases, unstable npm package combinations and the list goes on.

For one case, we decided to go completely native for each platform. However we don't want to lose our existing code completely.

I know this is a bit far fetched - but is there a way how to convert(at least partially) the javascript/ReactNative code into the pure-native Android code?

Is it even theoretically possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

As this [Expo Document](https://docs.expo.dev/workflow/prebuild/) suggests it is possible. You can generate native source code running a prebuild. In your terminal type `npx expo prebuild`. This should create the `ios/` and `android/` folders with the native code.